# Como substituir o conteúdo de um array?

Tags: javascript, html, array, for, array-associativo

Tenho uma `div` (mosaico de usuários) que dentro dela possui um `array` (javascript) com as fotos de usuários(dados vindo do banco). A quantidade de fotos de usuários devem ser menor ou igual a 15. Se caso o `array` tiver menos que 15 usuários(fotos), deve ser preenchido com um ícone ou imagem representando que está sem usuário.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Abaixo está um exemplo:

```
html += '<div class="mosaico-user wrap">'
        +   '<div class="liderGrupo"></div>';

var iconePadrao = '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x semUsuario" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
var demoParticipantes = ['<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><img src="/resources/img/teste1.jpg" class="fotousuario"></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><img src="/resources/img/teste.jpg" class="fotousuario"></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><img src="/resources/img/4.jpg" class="fotousuario"></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><img src="/resources/img/teste1.jpg" class="fotousuario"></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><img src="/resources/img/teste.jpg" class="fotousuario"></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><img src="/resources/img/4.jpg" class="fotousuario"></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><img src="/resources/img/teste1.jpg" class="fotousuario"></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><img src="/resources/img/teste.jpg" class="fotousuario"></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><img src="/resources/img/4.jpg" class="fotousuario"></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x usuarioSemFoto" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x usuarioSemFoto" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x usuarioSemFoto" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x usuarioSemFoto" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x semUsuario" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x semUsuario" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x semUsuario" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x semUsuario" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x semUsuario" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                        '<a class="linkUsuario" rel="popover" href="#" data-popover-content="#infoUser" data-toggle="popover"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x semUsuario" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'
                        ];
var conteudo = "";
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    conteudo = demoParticipantes[i];
    html += conteudo;
}
```

Comment: Claro! Se você prover algum código, de preferência o HTML e o javascript.

Comment: Desculpa. Adicionei um exemplo para facilitar.

Comment: Juro que por default eu ja fui codando e criei uma boa resposta, mas parei pra ler novamente sua pergunta e olhei pra minha resposta. Isso é uma coisa tão básica/fácil, esta parecendo que você nem tentou fazer e ja veio pedir ajuda. Por favor, mostre o que você fez e o que não esta funcionando que vamos lhe ajudar, dar a resposta assim logo de cara não rola aqui no StackOverflow, só pagando a hora $$.

Comment: Show, agora é só vc validar se seu array tem pelo 15 elementos, se não, você insere o valor do iconePadrão no array e dps itera e preenche o conteúdo.

Comment: cara poe o cod seu q puxa do db e etc  he bem mais facil na minha opiniao vc tratar na linguagem que puxa do db a qantidade de itens no array

Comment: Gente, sendo fácil ou dificil é uma questão válida. OP forneceu o código, se uma questão semelhante ja foi respondida só marcar como duplicada, senão os stackoverflowers estão aqui para ajudar. Acho que você pode postar sua solução @Giovane =]

Comment: @LucasCosta abri a questão e vi sem código e me bateu aquele feeling de GUJ com a galera querendo o trabalho feito e sem esforço.

Comment: Eu entendo você @Giovane, mas não foi sem esforço. Tentei de algumas formas aqui mas não consegui o resultado que eu queria. Inicialmente postei a pergunta, mas esqueci de inserir um códio exemplificando a minha tentativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte antes do seu `for` que insere o conteudo na variavel `html`.

```
while(demoParticipantes.length < 15) {
    demoParticipantes.push(iconePadrao);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Giovane, funcionou do jeito que eu esperava.

Comment: @AndréAlbson É nois!